# How to avoid "CopyTensor" in compile function with external call?

Tags: compile

I am writing a complicated compile function. To make it clear, I want to separate it into two smaller compile functions with one calling another. As you can see the example below, the `cf2` calling `cf1`

```
 cf1 = Compile[{{h, _Complex, 1}}, Module[{fab},
    fab = Table[0. I, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}];
    fab]];


 cf2 = Compile[{{h, _Complex, 1}}, Module[{fab},
    fab = cf1[h]
    ], CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];
```

The problem is that if you use `CompilePrint[cf2]` to check compiled code, there is "CopyTensor".

```
T(C1)1 = CopyTensor[ T(C1)0]]
```

I understand that "CopyTensor" is nothing but passing argument to another function, but it is a well known inefficient command. So, my question is is it possible to avoid that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `CopyTensor` is an artifact produced by inlining. Instead, you can try inlining with `With` as follows:

```
cf1 = Compile[{{h, _Complex, 1}},
   Table[0. I, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
cf2 = With[{cf1 = cf1},
   Compile[{{h, _Complex, 1}},
    cf1[h],
    CompilationTarget -> "C"
    ]
   ];
```

Now the pseudo code reads as

```
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[cf2]
```

> [...]
>
> 1  T(C2)1 = LibraryFunction[<>, compiledFunction11, {{Complex, 1, Constant}}, {Complex, 2}][ T(C1)0]]
>
> 2  Return

So we replaced the `CopyTensor` by a function call. Since in C, arrays are passed by reference, this should be faster than a `CopyTensor`. But I am not sure. One should try both variants and choose the one that performs better.

PS.: One can also try to set `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` in both `Compile`s. Then the critical lines of code looks like this:

> [...]
>
> 1  T(C2)1 = CompiledFunctionCall[ Hold[CompiledFunction[{h}, Table[0. I, {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}], -CompiledCode-]][ T(C1)0]]
>
> 2  Return

Sometimes, it is better to not leave the Wolfram Virtual Machine when frequently calling compiled functions by each other.

Comment: wow! It works exactly what I want! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 8):

You could use simple quoting mechanism to inline code of one function into another at top level.

```
ClearAll[quote, inline, unquote, eval]
SetAttributes[{quote, unquote}, HoldAllComplete]
quote@expr : Except@_Symbol := Unevaluated@expr /. {x : _unquote | _quote | _inline :> x, s_Symbol :> quote@s}
unquote@args___ := args
eval = # /. HoldPattern@quote@s_ :> s &;

inline::unsupported = "`1` is not one of function formats supported by inline.";
inline@HoldPattern@Function@body_ := Function@quote@body
inline@HoldPattern@Function[args_ , body_, attrs_ | PatternSequence[]] := Function[args, quote@body, attrs]
inline@HoldPattern@CompiledFunction[___, f_Function, ___] := inline@f
inline@f_ := (Message[inline::unsupported, HoldForm@f]; $Failed)
```

Note that such inlining will not exactly mimic behavior of function call in top level *Mathematica* code.
It'll fail if function result relies on argument evaluation, before they are passed to function body, or when single symbol used as function argument can represent `Sequence` of function arguments.
In top level code, above inlining works, for arbitrary arguments, only when inlined function has `HoldAllComplete` attribute, but for compiled functions neither evaluation control nor `Sequence` splicing is relevant.

In case from OP:

```
cf1 = Compile[{{h, _Complex, 1}}, Module[{fab},
  fab = Table[0. I,{a,1,5,1},{b,1,5,1}];
  fab
]];

cf2 = quote@Compile[{{h, _Complex, 1}},
  Module[{fab}, fab = inline[cf1]@h]
] // eval;

Needs@"CompiledFunctionTools`"
CompilePrint@cf2
(* ...
1   I2 = I1
2   I3 = I1
3   I5 = I6
4   T(C2)1 = Table[ I2, I3]
5   I4 = I6
6   goto 11
7   I7 = I6
8   goto 10
9   Element[ T(C2)1, I5] = C0
10  if[ ++ I7 <= I3] goto 9
11  if[ ++ I4 <= I2] goto 7
12  Return *)
```

Comment: That's a cute trick! Thanks!