# How to avoid “CopyTensor” in compile function with external call: the other case?

Tags: compile

I was very interested in the answer of [How to avoid “CopyTensor” in compile function with external call?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181646/how-to-avoid-copytensor-in-compile-function-with-external-call) and tried it on my own example below. And it does not work. Just curious why?

```
mvMu = With[{Part = Compile`GetElement}, 
  Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Module[{sum = 0}, Do[If[j[[k]] > i, sum++], {k, Length[j]}]; sum], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]
  ]


mvMuS = With[{mvMu = mvMu, Part = Compile`GetElement},
  Compile[{{i, _Integer, 1}, {j, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Module[{sum = 0}, Do[sum = sum + mvMu[j[[k]], i], {k, Length[j]}]; 
    sum], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
     "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"]]
```

The code still contains CopyTensor:

```
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[mvMuS]
```

> [...]
>
> 4 goto 21
>
> 5 I6 = GetElement[ T(I1)1, I5]
>
> 6 T(I1)2 = **CopyTensor**[ T(I1)0]]
>
> [...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just leave away the inlining options in `CompilationOptions`:

```
mvMu = With[{Part = Compile`GetElement}, 
  Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer, 1}}, 
   Module[{sum = 0}, 
    Do[If[j[[k]] > i, sum++], {k, Length[j]}]; 
    sum
   ], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"
   ]
  ]


mvMuS = With[{
   mvMu = mvMu,
   Part = Compile`GetElement
   },
  Compile[{{i, _Integer, 1}, {j, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{sum = 0},
    Do[sum = sum + mvMu[j[[k]], i], {k, Length[j]}];
    sum
    ], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"
    ]
   ]
```

Now, we have

```
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[mvMuS]
```

> [...]
>
> 1  I1 = I0
>
> 2  I4 = Length[ T(I1)1]
>
> 3  I5 = I0
>
> 4  goto 9
>
> 5  I6 = GetElement[T(I1)1, I5]
>
> 6  I7 = LibraryFunction[<>, compiledFunction20, {{Integer, 0, Constant}, {Integer, 1, Constant}}, Integer][ I6, T(I1)0]]
>
> 7  I6 = I1 + I7
>
> 8  I1 = I6
>
> 9  if[ ++ I5 <= I4] goto 5
>
> 10 Return

It should be clear by now that the automatic inlining by Mathematica is not that great... which is why I never use it.